# How to get the div to expand all over the screen even when the background content is modified?

Tags: css

I try to keep the div that spans the entire screen extended even when the background content changes. Please try the following example. The desired operation is that when clicking on the button the div with class windows continues to cover the entire screen

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector("ul").classList.toggle("hide");
});
```

```css
.window {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid goldenrod;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  padding: 20px;
}

ul.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="window"><button>Click me</button></div>

<ul class="hide">
  <li>Item-1</li>
  <li>Item-2</li>
  <li>Item-3</li>
  <li>Item-4</li>
  <li>Item-5</li>
  <li>Item-6</li>
  <li>Item-7</li>
  <li>Item-8</li>
  <li>Item-9</li>
  <li>Item-10</li>
  <li>Item-11</li>
  <li>Item-12</li>
  <li>Item-13</li>
  <li>Item-14</li>
  <li>Item-15</li>
  <li>Item-16</li>
  <li>Item-17</li>
  <li>Item-18</li>
  <li>Item-19</li>
  <li>Item-20</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector("ul").classList.toggle("hide");
});
```

```css
.window {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid goldenrod;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  padding: 20px;
}

ul.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="window"><button>Click me</button></div>

<ul class="hide">
  <li>Item-1</li>
  <li>Item-2</li>
  <li>Item-3</li>
  <li>Item-4</li>
  <li>Item-5</li>
  <li>Item-6</li>
  <li>Item-7</li>
  <li>Item-8</li>
  <li>Item-9</li>
  <li>Item-10</li>
  <li>Item-11</li>
  <li>Item-12</li>
  <li>Item-13</li>
  <li>Item-14</li>
  <li>Item-15</li>
  <li>Item-16</li>
  <li>Item-17</li>
  <li>Item-18</li>
  <li>Item-19</li>
  <li>Item-20</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: no actually, what I want is that when the background content appears the div with windows class expands so that the background content is still not displayed

Comment: @Mario check now.

Comment: Indeed, although I can't see that you have modified part of position fixed

Comment: Actually I had omitted the "background: #fff" earlier.